# Why is iter not a method of an instance and __iter__ is?

Tags: python, iterator, python-internals

The "intuitive" way of getting an iterator for someone who usually programs in Java, C++, etc is something like `list.iterator()`.

Why did the Python folks choose to have it as a general function like `len()` (which results in `iter(list)` rather than `list.iter()`)?

The same question can be asked for the length of a construct as well (`len()`).

Comment: Also related: [Special methods and interface-based type system](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-November/004643.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iter()` supports *different types of objects*.

You can pass in either a sequence (supporting length and item access) or an iterable (which produces an iterator by calling `obj.__iter__()`) or an iterator (which returns `self` from `__iter__`).

The Java `list.iter()` then is served by `list.__iter__()` in Python, but the `iter()` function allows for more types. You can customise the behaviour with a `__iter__` method but if you implemented a sequence instead, *things will still work*.

There is also a second form of the function where a callable and a sentinel are passed in:

```
iter(fileobj.readline, '')
```

iterates over a file object by calling the `readline()` method until it returns an empty string (equal to the second argument, the sentinel).

Then there is the [Principle of Least Astonishment](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/) argument; `iter()` gives the standard library a stable API call to standardise on, just like operators do; no need to look up the documentation of the class to see if it implemented `obj.iter()` or `obj.iterator()` or `obj.get_iterator()`.

Comment: So what you're saying is that `iter()` exists so that both sequence types and iterable types will have one method to get an iterator (which follows the Principle of least astonishment)?

Comment: @Shookie: That, and it's better HCI to have a post-fix function for core language features, just like operators exist to do arithmetic. You are not looking for `(4.3).divide_by(1.4)` either; you use `4.3 / 1.4` instead.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. Couldn't be the same thing implemented using `varioustypeofobject.iter()`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: sure, in the same way you can do `obj.length()` everywhere. And `int.divide()` and `float.add()`. But by using operators and post-fix functions you can provide a richer and more consistent API.

Comment: I don't see why it would be more richer and consistent. You can have and use operators with both approaches. To me, it looks like a language design decision, and both paths lead to a rich and consistent language. Can you give an example?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: how do you propose the `iter()`-with-two-arguments option is implemented as a method on objects? The whole point is to enable iteration for function calls that are not iterable from the start. Nor do standard sequence types have an iterator, so you'd complicate code that wants to support both sequences and iterables. And of course this is a language design decision.

Comment: huh? Why do you think that's a problem? It's just a different syntax. Example decision: You don't implement it, it comes with a language, it is a builtin, as it is in python. It calls the appropriate dunder magic functions, or whatever is needed, just as in python. But, again, decisions, if you want to ship the solution with the standard library, you can even implement the generic `iter()` in the base `object`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: sure, and the language already does that for a lot of things; but part of the language design is to use `__dunder__` method names for such methods and make them *hooks*; places for classes to provide alternate behaviour. This does enable richer behaviour; perhaps not for `iter()` but take a look how `__add__` and `__radd__` work; the interpreter consults both to find an object that can handle the addition, delegating to *the right object*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, that adds a richer behaviour. just as it would add if you had `o.iter()` or `o.len()`. You're talking about properties of the language that make it reach, not realising that in the parallel universe where you had `o.iter()`, the language would have the same properties and consequences.That universe also has `__add__`, it also has hooks. It has just a different syntax for the "outer" (e.g. `len`) abstraction.